# Trying to import SQL result into array: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted

Tags: php, mysql

I know other people have gotten this error, and have read threads to try and track down the issue, but my code is too different from other cases. There are about 150 records that should be returned from this specific query.

Below is my code that is causing the error:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM donor WHERE DonationAmount = 1000 AND Category = '1' or DonationAmount = 1000 AND Category IS NULL ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error!

EDIT: this is what I'm trying to do with said array.

```
$counter = 2;
$divisorCount = ceil($counter/2);
$forEachCount = 1;
foreach ($data as $row){
    $forEachCount++;
    $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['DisplayName']."</div>\n";
    if($forEachCount > $divisorCount){
        $forEachCount = 0;
        end($block);
        $key = key($block);
        $block[$key] .= "</div><div class='column'>"; // the insert
    }
}
unset($row,$key,$forEachCount,$divisorCount); //cleanup

$output = "<div class='tableContainer'>
 <div class='column'>".implode($block)."</div>
 </div>";
```

Comment: I'm guessing you exhausted the allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes.

Comment: No kidding... but that doesn't answer my question. The result set is only 150 **TEXT** field records. Shouldn't be using all the memory.

Comment: You're selecting * from donor. Select * drives DBA's crazy anyway. Do you have any CLOB's or similar that may be being returned (these may eat up lots of memory). What do you actually want to select from the donor table?

Comment: @JeffWatkins, I want to select a field called "DisplayName".

Comment: @DakotaWagner kidding aside - have you tried to narrow your selection critera? Another issue could be down to logic - have you tried putting parentheses around either side of the `or` arguments?

Comment: So SELECT DisplayName instead of SELECT *.

Comment: @JeffWatkins just tried specifying DisplayName, but still get the error.

Comment: Also - which line is the error happening at?

Comment: you should have parentheses around each of the AND criteria. when you did that try the query in command line / sql client or someting else to ensure you are getting the desired data (~150 entries)

Comment: @MacroMan I get the error on line 35, which would be the line where the while loop is located.

Comment: @SimonKraus upon putting the AND clauses in parentheses, I get this new error: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: You're using mysqli_fetch_array but as resulttype the constant MYSQL_ASSOC. try using MYSQLI_ASSOC

Comment: Do you actually need to keep the whole dataset in memory? Wouldn't just processing one row at a time (and immediately discarding it) help?

Comment: @Piskvor I did narrow the resultset down to one row instead of all rows of the table and still get problems.

Comment: pls type select length(DisplayName) in your SQL console and see what your column widths are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this, here while loop creating infinite loop, also check query conditions

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM donor WHERE (DonationAmount = 1000 AND Category = '1') or (DonationAmount = 1000 AND Category IS NULL) ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
```

Comment: I get this error when doing so: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Try with only `SELECT * FROM donor`?

Comment: When I do that, I get no result from the array at all.

Comment: You should get all data if you not put any condition in query, can you check your db connection  ?

Comment: DB connection is good. I will add to my question to hopefully make things make more sense.

Comment: please change `MYSQL_ASSOC` to `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

Comment: It still does the same thing.